CURL request with string variable and letter increment in url
Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
I'd like to return a list of valid urls, based on the following structure:
example.com/a
example.com/b
example.com/c

and so forth going all the way to site.com/zzzzzzzzzzzz
I managed to check the validity of the page with
curl -Is example.com/a | head -1

which returns a 404 error when the page doesn't exist.
I manage to do a loop like this:
for i in {{a..z},{a..z}{a..z},{a..z}{a..z}{a..z},{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z},{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z},{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z},{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z},{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z},{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z},{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}}
do
    echo "example.com/"$i 
    curl -Is example.com/$i | head -1
done

which tests all urls from a to zzzzzzzzzz
Is there a way to ignore all 404 errors and only return valid urls?

BASE_URL="example.com"

for path in {{-,{a..z}}{-,{a..z}}{-,{a..z}}{-,{a..z}}}
do
    url="$BASE_URL$path"

    STATUS_CODE=$(curl \
        --output /dev/null \
        --silent \
        --write-out "%{http_code}" \
        "$url")

  if (( STATUS_CODE != 404 ))
  then if (( STATUS_CODE = 200 ))
      then
        echo "$url"
      else
        echo STATUS_CODE
      fi
  fi
done

